# Filtering Java stream using a given parameter

Tags: java, spring, java-stream

I have a `List<MyObject>`:

```
My Object:
    String name;
    String team;
```

EDIT: I want to create a function that will filter this list using two parameters:

```
public List<MyObject> filterMyObjectList (String name, String state, List<MyObject> objectsList)
```

I need to create two filters:

The first will filter the MyObject by the name, and will add to the returned list only objects where the `MyObject.getName().equals(name)`.

The second will filter the MyObject by the team using another function that I have (`getState(MyObject.getTeam())`), and will add to the list only objects where the `getState(MyObject.getTeam()).equals(state)`.

Is there a way to write a predicate like this? Using a variable to compare?
Is there another way to filter using comparison?

Thanks!

Comment: You already have a couple of `filter` calls, so it's a bit unclear what exactly you're asking. Could you elaborate?

Comment: What do you want to filter? Describe your problem specificly, where are you stuck ?

Answer (score 1):

To do this you can just apply a filter:

```
public List<MyObject> filterMyObjectList (String name, String state, List<MyObject> objectsList) {
   return objectsList.stream()
                     .filter(obj -> obj.getName().equals(name) && getState(obj.getTeam()).equals(state))
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Since you are checking two conditions of the same object, you can aggregate them with `&&` in the `Predicate`